# If 2 players slam dunk at the same time, who got the score?

Tags: basketball

If 2 people touch the ball at the same time, who obtain the score in NBA?

Comment: Could you provide an example of where this has actually happened?

Comment: It sounds like a phenomenon which could occur in theory, but practically its almost impossible. Basketball being a team sport, even if 2 players from the same team jump for an offensive rebound, one will obviously reach the ball first. Thus, the player who is second will let his team mate complete the basket.

Comment: here's an example of where this has actually happened https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NebK55RscGY

Comment: It's pretty clear in that video that one player barely brushed the ball *before* being decisively dunked by the other.

Answer (score -1):

Although in theory its pretty much unrealistic but whoever owns up gets the 2 points. If you watch the NBA, you will notice that when it gets crowded in the paint and a player scored, the player that put his hand up is awarded the 2 points. The same would happen in your example.

If 2 players owns up to the basket, they will go through the slow motion and see which player had the most dominance of the ball (who held most of the ball).

Comment: Could you clarify whether this answer is based on knowledge of the actual NBA guidelines, or whether it is your personal observations? As per my comment on the original question, could you give an example of when they have actually referred to video evidence to determined who scored a basket?